# Store multiple authors in to couchbase database

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view, nosql

I am a newbie to "**couchbase** server". What i am looking for is to store 10 author names to couchbase document one after another. Someone please help me whether the structure is like a single document "author" and multiple values

`{ id : 1, name : Auther 1}, { id : 2, name : Author 2}`

OR store Author 1 to a document and Author 2 to another document.

If so, how can i increment the `id` automatically before "insert" command.

Answer (score 0):

you can store all authors in a single document

```
{  doctype : "Authors",
 AuthorNames:[
     {
     id: 1,
     Name : "author1"
      }
    {
    id: 2,
    Name : "author2"
    }
  so on
  ]
```

IF you want to increase the ID, one is to enter one author name at a time in new document, but ID will be randomly generated and it would not in incremental order.

Answer (score 0):

In Couchbase think more about how your application will be using the data more than how you are want to store it. For example, will your application need to get all of the 10 authors all of the time? If so, then one document might be worthwhile. Perhaps your application needs to only ever read/write one of the authors at a time. Then you might want to put each in their own, but have an object key pattern that makes it so you can get the object really fast. Objects that are used often are kept in the managed cache, other objects that are not used often may fall out of the managed cache...and that is ok.

The other factor is what your reads to writes ratio is on this data.

So like I said, it depends on how your application will be reading and writing your data. Use this as the guidance for how your data should be stored.

The single JSON document is pretty straight forward. The more advanced schema design where each author is in its own document and you access them via object key, might be a bit more complicated, but ultimately faster and more scalable depending on what I already pointed out. I will lay out an example schema and some possibilities.

For the authors, I might create each author JSON document with an object key like this:

authors::ID

Where ID is a value I keep in a special incrementer object that I will called authors::incrementer. Think of that object as a key value pair only holding an integer that happens to be the upper bound of an array. Couchbase SDKs include a special function to increment just such an integer object. With this, my application can put together that object key very quickly. If I want to go after the 5th author, I do a read by object key for "authors::5". If I need to get 10, I do a parallelized BulkGet function and get authors::1 through authors::10. If I want to get all the authors, I get the incrementer object, and get that integer and then to a parallelized bulk get. This way i can get them in order or in whatever order I feel like and I am accessing them by object key which is VERY fast in Couchbase.

All this being said, I could use a view to query this data or the upcoming "[SQL for Documents](http://query.couchbase.com/)" in Couchbase 4.0 or I can mix and match when I query and when I get objects by their key. Key access will ALWAYS be faster. It is the difference between asking a question then going and getting the object and simply knowing the answer and getting it immediately.